# An async function requires the 'Promise' constructor in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: typescript, fetch, visual-studio-2019

I have an MVC project that I am incorporating TypeScript into.  I have a tsconfig.json file that looks like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "Scripts",
    "outDir": "js",
    "lib": [ "es2015.promise", "es5", "dom", "es2015" ]
}
```

}

But in a file that I use the fetch method, I get the TS2705:(TS) An async function or method in ES5 / ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.
[image: screenshot]

So I am confused.  I thought the lib options in the tsconfig file fixed this error.  The project is explicitly using the tsconfig file and not the project properties.  When the file is compiled, there is a ton of code in it, which makes me think it is working and visual studio just isn't pulling something in.  Is there a way to fix this error?